# How can I redirect a Laravel route without a parameter to a controller method with a default parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Assume the following routes in a Laravel 5.5 API:

```
// custom routes for THIS user (the user making the request)
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('/user/edit', 'UserController@edit');

// register CRUDdy resource routes for users
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Let's use `edit` as the example:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the edit route contains a type-hinted `$user` parameter. This works just fine for the `users/13/edit` route, as expected. However, I'd to configure the route `/user/edit` to pass along the `$request->user()` user object to the function. I don't want to check for the user object *in* the actual `edit` method as that could interfere with other validation (for instance, I don't want to default to the current user if someone passes a non-existent user ID, I want to return an error in that case).

In short: how can I register a route to first create a parameter, then pass it to the given controller method? My first thought was to use a closure:

```
Route::get('/user/edit', function(Request $request){
    $user = $request->user();
});
```

But once inside the closure, I'm not certain how to then carry the request forward to the appropriate controller method.

Comment: are you sure this function is generated by artisan like using `--resource` tag

Comment: Yes, the resource routes were generated by artisan. I want to add additional routes, like I say in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a closure, you could make a new controller method that calls edit with the current user.

Let's say your route is this:

```
Route::get('/user/edit', 'UserController@editSelf');
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function editSelf(Request $request)
{
    $this->edit($request->user());
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most straightforward and typical way of handling the scenario, thanks!